# How to properly remove Chinese support

Tags: 15.10, language-support

I have successfully installed language support for Chinese language through Language Support > Install Remove / Languages ... > Chinese (simplified).

While I am testing multi-language support for my application, I wanted to test some stuff with support for certain language and without system supporting the language.

After removing Chinese the same way I installed it, my system now continues to correctly display Chinese characters even if Chinese support is uninstalled. So my testing is now paused, I want to figure out what else was installed and not uninstalled with me clicking check-box and uninstalling Chinese (simplified).

What else should I uninstall, may be some fonts or other stuff? Is there any way to find out what packages each language check-box installs in Ubuntu Language Support to make it universal, because after Chinese I am moving to other languages too?

I did logout, reboot, to make sure settings are applied, did not help. I am adding relevant [/var/log/dpkg.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14006951/)

Output of `locale` command:

```
mike@pm33:~$ locale 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
LANGUAGE=en_US 
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8" 
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8 
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Please show us the output of the `locale` command.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I appended my question with `locale` command.

Comment: Ok.. So, what is the actual problem, then? I can tell you that any Ubuntu system has the ability to display Chinese characters, since the fonts-droid package is installed by default, whether the dedicated Chinese support packages have been installed or not.

Comment: That is not true, I have several default 15.10 desktop installations updated and upgraded to this date running now here in one room and only those with Chinese installed display characters correctly, I am talking about filenames in Nautilus and Nemo, standard characters in Firefox and Chrome .... if not installed, then it is showing rectangles instead of characters.

Comment: So what about the presence of the fonts-droid package?`It's a recommended package in the ubuntu-desktop package, and hence installed automatically when installing Ubuntu 15.10.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson It looks like there is group of droid fonts, but have a look at my `fc-list | grep droid` it is all but Chinese http://paste.ubuntu.com/14012462/

Comment: The `DroidSansFallbackFull.ttf` font is the one which permits display of Chinese characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [/var/log/dpkg.log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14006951/) I found that fonts-arphic-uming and fonts-arphic-ukai are installed with Chinese language pack and they are not uninstalled when language pack is removed.

```
sudo apt-get purge fonts-arphic-ukai
sudo apt-get purge fonts-arphic-uming
```

Removing these two packages returned Ubuntu to it's original setup.

Comment: Good that you figured out what you were after. Your description, that fonts-droid (i.e. Droid Sans Fallback) isn't sufficient to display Chinese characters, confused me. Still does, actually.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I was testing only unicode supplementary characters as they are important for my application to work, so standard characters are displayed fine. I am new in this area, so I have a checklist and proceed, but these supplementary characters may be part of person's name and other important stuff, I want them to work.